Google Calendar duplicating tasks beetwen secondary calendar and main one
I have an API that sends requests to Google Calendar to insert a new event. I have the default calendar and a second one (let's call it 'X') to store some specific events. For some reason, when I send a request to insert a task in the 'X' calendar, the same task is also created in the default one. I couldn't find anything in the documentation that would help me. Any insight would be greatly appreciated, as some of our clients are experiencing this issue.
Endpoint that i'm using to send the request: https://www.googleapis.com/calendars/('X'calendarId)/events?sendNotifications=true
Headers: "Authorization", "Bearer AccessToken"
Body is a application/json
{
  "summary": "test",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": null,
    "date": "2024-04-25",
    "timeZone": "America/Fortaleza"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": null,
    "date": "2024-04-26",
    "timeZone": "America/Fortaleza"
  },
  "status": "confirmed",
  "guestsCanModify": true,
  "attendees": [
    {
      "email": "pederzinipederzini@gmail.com",
      "responseStatus": "accepted"
    }
  ],
  "extendedProperties": {
    "private": {
      "internalId": 20148
    }
  }
}

Edit
Add more informations as asked in the comments ( I just changed some Ids for '.')
calendar.events.list from my main calendar:
{
"kind": "calendar#events",
    "etag": "\"p32od5p6ihrcoa0o\"",
    "summary": "pederzinipederzini@gmail.com",
    "description": "",
    "updated": "2024-04-23T19:54:01.246Z",
    "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo",
    "accessRole": "owner",
    "defaultReminders": [
     {
      "method": "popup",
      "minutes": 30
     }
    ],
    "nextSyncToken": "-----------------------------",
    "items": [
   ....
      {
      "kind": "calendar#event",
      "etag": "\"3427103973430000\"",
      "id": "..................",
      "status": "confirmed",
      "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event? eid=........................",
      "created": "2024-04-19T18:39:45.000Z",
      "updated": "2024-04-19T18:39:46.715Z",
      "summary": "Mais um teste",
      "creator": {
       "email": "pederzinipederzini@gmail.com",
       "self": true
      },
      "organizer": {
       "email": ".....................@group.calendar.google.com",
       "displayName": "Calendar 2"
      },
      "start": {
       "date": "2024-04-25"
      },
      "end": {
       "date": "2024-04-26"
      },
      "iCalUID": "qp9ubmu0vageearvrbvqqhr7c0@google.com",
      "sequence": 0,
      "attendees": [
       {
        "email": "pederzinipederzini@gmail.com",
        "self": true,
        "responseStatus": "accepted"
       }
      ],
      "guestsCanModify": true,
      "reminders": {
       "useDefault": false
      },
      "eventType": "default"
     },
     {
      "kind": "calendar#event",
      "etag": "\"3427804082492000\"",
      "id": "............",
      "status": "confirmed",
      "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=............",
      "created": "2024-04-23T19:54:00.000Z",
      "updated": "2024-04-23T19:54:01.246Z",
      "summary": "test25",
      "creator": {
       "email": "pederzinipederzini@gmail.com",
       "self": true
      },
      "organizer": {
       "email": ".......@group.calendar.google.com",
       "displayName": "Calendar 2"
      },
      "start": {
       "date": "2024-04-25"
      },
      "end": {
       "date": "2024-04-26"
      },
      "iCalUID": "...........@google.com",
      "sequence": 0,
      "attendees": [
       {
        "email": "pederzinipederzini@gmail.com",
        "self": true,
        "responseStatus": "accepted"
       }
      ],
      "guestsCanModify": true,
      "reminders": {
       "useDefault": false
      },
      "eventType": "default"
     }
    ]

calendar.events.list from my secondary calendar:
{
    "kind": "calendar#events",
    "etag": "\"p33s8j8eihrcoa0o\"",
    "summary": "Calendar 2",
    "description": "",
    "updated": "2024-04-23T19:54:00.139Z",
    "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo",
    "accessRole": "owner",
    "defaultReminders": [],
    "nextSyncToken": "-----------------------",
    "items": [
    .....
    {
      "kind": "calendar#event",
      "etag": "\"3427103970972000\"",
      "id": ".....................",
      "status": "confirmed",
      "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=cXA5dWJtdTB2YWdlZWFydnJidnFxaHI3YzAgNzNhZWFlMGU3MzgwOTY1NzMwZWFjYmY3ZjIxYzg2NzFiYThlYTM3ZTFkN2VkZjkwYTcyZjQzNTQyNGM3NTQ3OEBn",
      "created": "2024-04-19T18:39:45.000Z",
      "updated": "2024-04-19T18:39:45.486Z",
      "summary": "Mais um teste",
      "creator": {
       "email": "pederzinipederzini@gmail.com"
      },
      "organizer": {
       "email": "....................@group.calendar.google.com",
       "displayName": "Calendar 2",
       "self": true
      },
      "start": {
       "date": "2024-04-25"
      },
      "end": {
       "date": "2024-04-26"
      },
      "iCalUID": "qp9ubmu0vageearvrbvqqhr7c0@google.com",
      "sequence": 0,
      "attendees": [
       {
        "email": "pederzinipederzini@gmail.com",
        "responseStatus": "accepted"
       }
      ],
      "extendedProperties": {
       "private": {
        "ploomesId": "601126148"
       }
      },
      "guestsCanModify": true,
      "reminders": {
       "useDefault": false
      },
      "eventType": "default"
     },
     {
      "kind": "calendar#event",
      "etag": "\"3427804080278000\"",
      "id": "p1j259vq0i9i17u8ug0rfl3g7s",
      "status": "confirmed",
      "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=cDFqMjU5dnEwaTlpMTd1OHVnMHJmbDNnN3MgNzNhZWFlMGU3MzgwOTY1NzMwZWFjYmY3ZjIxYzg2NzFiYThlYTM3ZTFkN2VkZjkwYTcyZjQzNTQyNGM3NTQ3OEBn",
      "created": "2024-04-23T19:54:00.000Z",
      "updated": "2024-04-23T19:54:00.139Z",
      "summary": "test25",
      "creator": {
       "email": "pederzinipederzini@gmail.com"
      },
      "organizer": {
       "email": "........................@group.calendar.google.com",
       "displayName": "Calendar 2",
       "self": true
      },
      "start": {
       "date": "2024-04-25"
      },
      "end": {
       "date": "2024-04-26"
      },
      "iCalUID": "...............@google.com",
      "sequence": 0,
      "attendees": [
       {
        "email": "pederzinipederzini@gmail.com",
        "responseStatus": "accepted"
       }
      ],
      "extendedProperties": {
       "private": {
        "internalId": "20148"
       }
      },
      "guestsCanModify": true,
      "reminders": {
       "useDefault": false
      },
      "eventType": "default"
     }
    ]



please edit your question and include [example]

@LindaLawton-DaImTo thank you for your reply, I added more informations. I was able to reproduce using postman and the informations above.

can you do a calendar.events.list i want to see it respond with it in both.   also add the response from postman.

@LindaLawton-DaImTo That's the  calendar.events.list of both main and secondary calendars, I just added the last two events
